# Code-first EF 5 to EF 6 upgrade issues - invalid object name 'dbo.name'

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Upgraded EF 5 to 6 and I am getting the invalid oject name 'dbo.name' on this line of code:

var users = _repo.AllIncluding(u => u.Roles, u=>u.CostCentres).OrderBy(u => u.UserName).ToList()

We are using the Repository Pattern

Comment: can you write the method AllIncluding

Comment: `public IQueryable<User> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<User, object>>[] includeProperties)
        {
            IQueryable<User> query = context.Users;

            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }
            return query;
        }`